# WYSIWYG Image editors for domain-specific QA's?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, editor, images

I think I just had a pretty good idea: could we have domain-specific WYSIWYG editors (like miniature / context specific image editors) for specific Stacks? Here are some uses:

- a circuit diagram editor for electrical engineering
- a graph editor (both 2d and 3d) for math.stackexchange + physics
- a chemical structure diagramming tool
- automatic data graphing tools for cross validated
- a mockup tool for web applications + user experience
- a map editor for GIS
- a map editor for game development
- something simple to add arrows, circles, highlights etc to existing images

Of course each set of tools would have to be tailor-made for each QA, and we would have to find a sponsor for the generated images to be hosted (like imageshack, imgur or something), but this could totally be done. We could use paper.js or processing.js to do the rendering, and then each tool could be plugged into the related QA's editor.

What do you think? Shall I get to programming?

Comment: I don't think we should do that. You should use the tools that fit your job, you should not create tables with Word, but with Excel. That's the same for SE, you should not modify images in an online QA site, but in a tool that's made for editing images

Comment: EE just recently added an [embedded circuit editor](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/2708/2724), UX has an [embedded Balsamiq editor](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/a/871) for mockups, and Chess has a nice [interactive replayer](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/a/175/215).  It looks like @balpha is on this.  :)

Comment: Awesome thanks @BilltheLizard!! I'll see if we can work on a webgl graphing tool for physics/math, and some kind of chemistry tool (if needed). Thank you :)
And @WouterJ, you can still edit spreadsheets with google docs :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What site-specific post formatting settings are available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298843/what-site-specific-post-formatting-settings-are-available)

Answer (score 2):

[As Bill the Lizard mentioned,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170931/wysiwyg-image-editors-for-domain-specific-qas#comment505759_170931) we do try to give each community the tools they best need to illustrate their questions and answers. We've done this for a number of sites already:

- [Embedded Circuit Lab editor](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/embedding-a-schematic-editor/2708#2708) on [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com)
- [Embedded Balsamiq editor](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/870/allow-new-users-to-post-mockups/871#871) on [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com)
- [Interactive replayer](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/can-we-implement-a-replayer-for-chess-analysis-on-the-site/175#175) on [Chess](http://chess.stackexchange.com)
- [Go markup](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/642/2162) for [Board & Card Games](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com)
- [Card renderer](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/a/77) for [Poker](http://poker.stackexchange.com)
- [MathJax syntax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) on [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com)

There may be others that don't pop into my mind immediately.

If there is a specific Stack Exchange site that you believe is lacking a tool specific to that audience, let us know. We evaluate these on a case by case basis, but we really do want to provide the best tools we can for each community. You're of course welcome to write your own scripts if you'd like, but if there's a true need for additional tools, our dev team will take care of it. :)