# What site-specific post formatting settings are available?

Tags: support, markdown, faq-proposed, site-specific, site-specific-formatting

Certain Stack Exchange sites have specialized support for non-standard types of post formatting.

Tim Post briefly mentioned these when discussing [site-specific configuration settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/249722/351462), but he didn't go into much detail.

- Which sites have site-specific formatting?
- What are the different site-specific formatting types?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Certain Stack Exchange sites have specialized support for non-standard types of post formatting.

- **[Balsamiq Mockups](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/647/can-stackexchange-license-balsamiq-for-mockups-on-ux-stackexchange)**: Displays mockups for user interfaces

  - [User Experience](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/647/can-stackexchange-license-balsamiq-for-mockups-on-ux-stackexchange)
- **[Card renderer](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/3247)**: Displays card hands

  - [Poker](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/3247)
- **[Chess Replayer](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179/how-do-i-add-a-replayer-to-my-post)**: Display chess positions and games

  - [Chess](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179/how-do-i-add-a-replayer-to-my-post)
- **[CircuitLab schematics](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/963/113522)**: Displays and simulates electrical circuits

  - [Electronics](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/963/113522)
- **[Cross-site internal links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297972/enable-internal-link-translation-for-all-stack-exchange-communities)**: Translate question URLs from any SE site into question titles

  - [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297972/enable-internal-link-translation-for-all-stack-exchange-communities)
- **[Furigana](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199/jlu-hacks-ruby-rendering)**: support for Japanese phonetic annotations

  - [Japanese Language](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199/jlu-hacks-ruby-rendering), [Anime & Manga](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/673/can-we-get-furigana-support-here)
- **[Go board renderer](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/425/12315)**: Displays Go boards

  - [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/425/12315)
- **[Highlight.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)**: Provides syntax highlighting for code

  - [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) and [some other technical sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314553/which-stack-exchange-sites-have-syntax-highlighting-enabled)
- **[jTab and ABCjs](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2581/jtab-and-abcjs-formatting-sandbox)**: Rendering of sheet music and guitar tabs

  - [Music Practice & Theory](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2581/jtab-and-abcjs-formatting-sandbox)
- **[Magic: The Gathering Autocard links](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/726/12315)**: Automatic links to MTG cards on the official website

  - [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/726/12315)
- **[MathJax/LaTeX](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax)**: Display advanced mathematical formulas

  - [Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/778/unnecessary-message-about-mathjax-loading), [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/434/test-the-new-latex-markdown-in-this-sandbox-question), [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [many more sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax)
  - Certain sites have special configurations for MathJax:

    - The [mhchem extension](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26/enable-mhchem-mathjax-extension) has been enabled on [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) and some other sites, noted in the list of sites with MathJax linked above.
    - Some sites use `\$` delimiters to denote MathJax instead of the normal `$`; these sites are also noted in that list.
- **[SoundCloud embedding](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled)**: Embed music from SoundCloud

  - [Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3616/could-we-get-the-audio-embedding-feature-for-ppcg), [Music Practice & Theory](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled), [Signal Processing](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/is-there-a-way-to-upload-audio-clips), [Video Production](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled)
- **[YouTube embedding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297500/which-sites-have-youtube-embedding-on)**: Embed YouTube videos

  - [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10676/embed-youtube-videos-using-the-html5-player), [Movies & TV](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2105/supported-urls-for-video-embedding/3931), [Music Practice & Theory](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled), [SciFi & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2210/could-we-get-youtube-embedding) and [many more sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297500/295232)