# Searching for meta posts on the Stack Exchange network

Tags: support, search, per-site-meta

I want to do a network-wide search that covers all meta sites on Stack Exchange.

Specifically, I'm looking to find [site-specific announcement posts](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled) so I can research which communities have [site-specific formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298844/351462) enabled.

I've tried using the [Network Wide search](https://stackexchange.com/search), but it seems that `is:meta` isn't a valid search option.

**How can I search for meta posts across the Stack Exchange network?**

Preferably, I would like to sort the results by votes, as feature announcements like these tend to be highly voted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use Google custom search on the network-wide search page, not an in-house search engine. The benefit of this is that the custom search is *already* scoped to only our network sites.

You can still further scope it using Google's `site:` search operator, which happens to support wildcards. So something like this would search for a particular term on all sites that have meta in their URL:

[`site:meta.* MathJax`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.*%20MathJax)

Comment: Is it possible to sort the results by votes?

Comment: No. Google does not have any comprehension of post scores.

Comment: I want to make my search exclude Meta Stack Exchange. I've tried [`site:meta.* -site:meta.stackexchange.* MathJax`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.*%20-site%3Ameta.stackexchange.*%20MathJax), but that also excludes `<site>.meta.stackexchange.com`

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if Google allows such a search parameter.

Comment: After experimenting a bit, [`site:meta.* site:*.meta.stackexchange.* YouTube`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.*+site%3A*.meta.stackexchange.*+YouTube) seems to work pretty well.