# Which Stack Exchange sites have syntax highlighting enabled?

Tags: support, markdown, syntax-highlighting, faq-proposed

The code [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) feature is only enabled on certain sites. In order for code to be highlighted and for any of the hints listed in the above question to work, the Markdown extension has to be enabled on the site where one's posting code.

- Which sites have this enabled?
- How do I request that it be enabled on [site X]?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Which Stack Exchange sites have syntax highlighting enabled?

The syntax highlighting feature is enabled on the following sites:

1. [Arduino](//arduino.stackexchange.com)
2. [Arduino Meta](//arduino.meta.stackexchange.com)
3. [Ask Different](//apple.stackexchange.com)
4. [Ask Ubuntu](//askubuntu.com)
5. [Bioinformatics](//bioinformatics.stackexchange.com)
6. [Bioinformatics Meta](//bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com)
7. [Bitcoin](//bitcoin.stackexchange.com)
8. [Blender](//blender.stackexchange.com)
9. [CS50](//cs50.stackexchange.com)
10. [CS50 Meta](//cs50.meta.stackexchange.com)
11. [Cardano](//cardano.stackexchange.com)
12. [Cardano Meta](//cardano.meta.stackexchange.com)
13. [Chemistry](//chemistry.stackexchange.com)
14. [Chemistry Meta](//chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com)
15. [Code Golf](//codegolf.stackexchange.com)
16. [Code Golf Meta](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com)
17. [Code Review](//codereview.stackexchange.com)
18. [Computational Science](//scicomp.stackexchange.com)
19. [Computer Graphics](//computergraphics.stackexchange.com)
20. [Computer Graphics Meta](//computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com)
21. [Computer Science](//cs.stackexchange.com)
22. [Computer Science Educators](//cseducators.stackexchange.com)
23. [Computer Science Educators Meta](//cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com)
24. [Computer Science Meta](//cs.meta.stackexchange.com)
25. [Craft CMS](//craftcms.stackexchange.com)
26. [Craft CMS Meta](//craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com)
27. [Cross Validated](//stats.stackexchange.com)
28. [Data Science](//datascience.stackexchange.com)
29. [Data Science Meta](//datascience.meta.stackexchange.com)
30. [Database Administrators](//dba.stackexchange.com)
31. [DevOps](//devops.stackexchange.com)
32. [DevOps Meta](//devops.meta.stackexchange.com)
33. [Drupal Answers](//drupal.stackexchange.com)
34. [EOS.IO](//eosio.stackexchange.com)
35. [EOS.IO Meta](//eosio.meta.stackexchange.com)
36. [Electrical Engineering](//electronics.stackexchange.com)
37. [Emacs](//emacs.stackexchange.com)
38. [Emacs Meta](//emacs.meta.stackexchange.com)
39. [Ethereum](//ethereum.stackexchange.com)
40. [Ethereum Meta](//ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com)
41. [Game Development](//gamedev.stackexchange.com)
42. [Geographic Information Systems](//gis.stackexchange.com)
43. [Graphic Design](//graphicdesign.stackexchange.com)
44. [Graphic Design Meta](//graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com)
45. [Internet of Things](//iot.stackexchange.com)
46. [Internet of Things Meta](//iot.meta.stackexchange.com)
47. [Magento](//magento.stackexchange.com)
48. [Magento Meta](//magento.meta.stackexchange.com)
49. [Mathematica](//mathematica.stackexchange.com)
50. [Matter Modeling](//mattermodeling.stackexchange.com)
51. [Meta Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com)
52. [Meta Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com)
53. [Meta Super User](//meta.superuser.com)
54. [Operations Research](//or.stackexchange.com)
55. [Operations Research Meta](//or.meta.stackexchange.com)
56. [Programming Language Design and Implementation](//langdev.stackexchange.com)
57. [Programming Language Design and Implementation Meta](//langdev.meta.stackexchange.com)
58. [Proof Assistants](//proofassistants.stackexchange.com)
59. [Quantitative Finance](//quant.stackexchange.com)
60. [Quantitative Finance Meta](//quant.meta.stackexchange.com)
61. [Quantum Computing](//quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com)
62. [Quantum Computing Meta](//quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com)
63. [Raspberry Pi](//raspberrypi.stackexchange.com)
64. [Raspberry Pi Meta](//raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com)
65. [Reverse Engineering](//reverseengineering.stackexchange.com)
66. [Reverse Engineering Meta](//reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com)
67. [Robotics](//robotics.stackexchange.com)
68. [Salesforce](//salesforce.stackexchange.com)
69. [Salesforce Meta](//salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com)
70. [Server Fault](//serverfault.com)
71. [SharePoint](//sharepoint.stackexchange.com)
72. [Signal Processing](//dsp.stackexchange.com)
73. [Signal Processing Meta](//dsp.meta.stackexchange.com)
74. [Sitecore](//sitecore.stackexchange.com)
75. [Sitecore Meta](//sitecore.meta.stackexchange.com)
76. [Software Engineering](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)
77. [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](//sqa.stackexchange.com)
78. [Software Quality Assurance & Testing Meta](//sqa.meta.stackexchange.com)
79. [Stack Apps](//stackapps.com)
80. [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com)
81. [Stack Overflow Meta en español](//es.meta.stackoverflow.com)
82. [Stack Overflow em Português](//pt.stackoverflow.com)
83. [Stack Overflow em Português Meta](//pt.meta.stackoverflow.com)
84. [Stack Overflow en español](//es.stackoverflow.com)
85. [Stack Overflow на русском](//ru.stackoverflow.com)
86. [Stack Overflow на русском Meta](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com)
87. [Stellar](//stellar.stackexchange.com)
88. [Stellar Meta](//stellar.meta.stackexchange.com)
89. [Substrate and Polkadot](//substrate.stackexchange.com)
90. [Super User](//superuser.com)
91. [TeX - LaTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com)
92. [TeX - LaTeX Meta](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com)
93. [Tridion](//tridion.stackexchange.com)
94. [Unix & Linux](//unix.stackexchange.com)
95. [Vi and Vim](//vi.stackexchange.com)
96. [Video Production](//video.stackexchange.com)
97. [Video Production Meta](//video.meta.stackexchange.com)
98. [Webmasters](//webmasters.stackexchange.com)
99. [Webmasters Meta](//webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com)
100. [WordPress Development](//wordpress.stackexchange.com)
101. [スタック・オーバーフロー](//ja.stackoverflow.com)
102. [スタック・オーバーフローMeta](//ja.meta.stackoverflow.com)

Note that the above list consists of per-site metas as well, as there are some sites where it's enabled on the main site but not on the corresponding per-site meta. The above list was last updated 2023-08-13; if it becomes outdated, please copy the Markdown generated by the below code snippet and replace the above list with that, and then update the date here.

The following code snippet fetches the list of sites with syntax highlighting enabled.

```js
$.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites?pagesize=500&filter=!*L6SiaRiUSk*Z2zr', function(data) {
    var i,
        $result = $('#result'),
        $md = $('#md'),
        sites = [],
        specials = {
          biology : { mhchem: true},
          chemistry: {mhchem: true },
          earthscience: {mhchem: true },
          electricalengineering: {delim: true},
          codereview: {delim: true}
          },
        sec,
        extra;
     for(i=0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
       if (data.items[i].markdown_extensions &&
           data.items[i].markdown_extensions.indexOf('Prettify')>-1) //Even after the changeover to Highlight.js, the Markdown extension is still called "Prettify"
         {
            sites.push(data.items[i]);
         }
       }
    sites.sort(function(l,r) { return l.name<r.name?-1:1; });
    for(i = 0; i < sites.length; i = i + 1) {
        $result.append(
            $('<li></li>').html(sites[i].name)
        );
        $md.append(
           $('<pre></pre>').html('1. [' + sites[i].name+'](' + sites[i].site_url.substr(sites[i].site_url.indexOf(':') + 1) + ')')
        );
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="result">
</ol>

<div id="md">
</div>
```

The above snippet was originally written by rene [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/377214) for fetching the list of sites with MathJax enabled, and later modified [with the help of user315433 in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6845211#6845211) to support fetching the list of sites with syntax highlighting enabled.

### How do I request that syntax highlighting be enabled on [site X]?

Normally, syntax highlighting will be enabled by staff when newly creating the site, based on the scope of the site's Area 51 proposal and how strongly it is focused on programming. If it's not enabled on a given site, you can post a request on the per-site meta tagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [syntax-highlighting](/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting) to have it enabled in the following cases:

- The site topic is primarily focused on programming, but syntax highlighting wasn't enabled due to oversight.
- The site topic isn't primarily focused on programming, but the site could substantially benefit from one or more particular flavors of syntax highlighting. In this case, link to some (10 or so) posts where highlighting would be helpful in your request.
- Syntax highlighting is enabled on a main site but not on its per-site meta, and you feel it's useful to have enabled on the meta site. In this case, ensure your request has the [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) tag and clearly explains that it's asking about the meta site.

If there is community consensus in support of such a request, a site moderator can add the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to the meta post to [escalate it for staff attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348642/what-posts-should-be-escalated-to-staff-using-status-review-and-how-do-i-esca). SE staff will then evaluate the request and let you know the result.

Comment: @Slate When you update the post per the script, can you please also update the date the post was updated?

Comment: Sure, thanks. Missed that.

Comment: Is it possible to update syntax highlighting in Ask Ubuntu? Highlight for `nginx` is not working, while in Stack Overflow it does. There's a similar question on Meta about that [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355233/229165)