# Does the Stack Exchange engine support addons/plugins?

Tags: feature-request, posts, addon

For example there's the following idea on [Medical Sciences Meta](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1109/consider-adding-descriptive-popups-for-parts-of-the-body-that-are-mentioned-in-a/1111#1111)

> As a non specialist I would strongly suggest a way to anatomically
>   show the mentioned parts of the body in optional popups maybe, that
>   appear when user hovers over the given latin term. Otherwise we -
>   regular people struggle to understand the text.

As a web-developer I see how it can be done, however it's obviously not possible if there's no way to customize Stack Exchange instance.

Comment: There are a bunch of user scripts made by other users published on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it does, and several sites are already using it: [What site-specific post formatting settings are available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298843/295232)

Of course, this requires some development on the Stack Exchange part as well. [Here](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/169/7297) is an example where one of the users wrote an open source JavaScript plugin for replaying chess games, and the Stack Exchange development team decided to integrate it into the Chess Stack Exchange website. Once that works (and users writing posts use the appropriate syntax), it's working for *everyone* visiting the website, including anonymous visitors.

Alternatively (but this requires additional action on the part of the users *viewing* the post), one could develop a [user script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) which triggers upon certain Latin terms in posts, and modifies the website slightly to provide the desired functionality. Stack Apps has a [list of userscripts](https://stackapps.com/tags/script) from which you can draw some inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

Make a userscript, or browser extension and post it on stackapps.com .

Look for some boilerplate webextension source code, and add whatever custom javascript you want in there if you're unfamiliar with browser extension development.

If you do, I suggest you open-source it so you aren't stuck with maintenance for the rest of your life.