# Is there anything specifically like Stack Exchange and not like Stack Overflow available that caters to a scientific organisation/individual?

Tags: discussion

I have seen the enterprise edition of Stack Exchange and the various plans associated to this product. However when I tried it out, I was disappointed in its features.

What I am after is something specifically in the Stack Exchange format, good examples are:

- mathematica
- physics
- mathematics

My end goal is to use SE as a kind of electronic lab book for academic research/experiments. So things like the ability to insert images and having LaTeX or math markup languages are pretty essential. This doesn't seem to be available on SO.

How can I get my own private SE? Or something that is almost the same as it.

---

Just so it's clear my requirements are:

- The ability to paste in images (Teams ✔)
- To have LaTeX or math markup i.e. so one can go $E = m c^{2}$ for inline expressions or $$ \bar{\psi} \left( i \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} - m \right) \psi = 0$$ for a full equation (Teams ?)
- Code chunks/snippets (Teams ✔)
- The ability to customise the interface appearance -- ideally something more along the lines of SE (Teams ?)

I will contact teams at the suggestion of one of the users who made a comment on this post and respond.

In the meantime, if anyone knows of a way to implement what I want, or, alternative software I'd be very interested to know!

Comment: How "Private" are you saying? Is this for a business? Is this for personal use? (How would that even work?)

Comment: The closest comparison would be for a experimental collaboration, a collection of academics working on an experiment or project. A private one would also be very much acceptable.

Comment: Doesn't [teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) fit the bill? If it doesn't, why not?

Comment: As I mentioned, I have tried this and there is no LaTeX or math markup support -- or customisation of the interface to resemble something more like SE. If I can get LaTeX or MathM then this could work!

Comment: LaTeX isn't "specific" to SE or those sites - it's a global feature that can be turned on/off with a setting, and it's just only turned on for sites that need it. I don't remember if it can be turned on in Teams, but if you're interested in the product and have a need for it, contacting Teams support to request it is the way to go.

Comment: @animuson thanks I'll give that a go.

Comment: There's a [bunch of different things, including MathJax and Videos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298843/282094) that *could* be asked about.

Comment: Maybe after you contacted the support, you could come back here and answer your question yourself. I would find it interesting.

Comment: "My end goal is to use SE as a kind of electronic lab book for academic research/experiments": what does this have to do with Q&A software? It sounds like you're looking for a latex workflow (e.g. based on git or Overleaf), or possibly a more general tool like https://osf.io . See also https://101innovations.wordpress.com/outcomes/

Comment: @Nemo Because the format of SE/SO is pretty perfect. Just because it was designed as a Q&A ticket system doesn't prohibit it's use in other ways. For example one would write instead of a question "Voltage fluctuation study" and post results in the form of answers. Clicking accepted could indicate experiment completed or whatever criteria.

Comment: @Trilarion absolutely! I have contacted them and am waiting for a response.

Comment: @Q.P. so you're looking for an issue tracker of sorts? See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_project_management_software