# Prerequisites to enable mhchem on a site

Tags: support, mathjax, site-specific-formatting

mhchem offers some advantages with respect to MathJax when writing chemical formulas and so on.

What are the prerequisites that need to be satisfied in order to have mhchem enabled on a given site?

Comment: Linked question on WB:SE's Meta here: [Can we extend mhchem support in MathJax to include physical units?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9710/80336)

Comment: Worth noting that mhchem is technically available on all MathJax sites; it just needs to be called manually on sites where it's not preloaded automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As with all [site-specific formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298843/295232), it needs to be enabled by staff, and they usually do so after it's clear that there's enough support from the community, which is usually gathered through a question on the community's meta like [Can we extend mhchem support in mathjax to include physical units?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9710/8732). So that part is done.

When it has gathered enough support, you can tag it with [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) and a Community Manager will have a look at it. Sometimes, requests like that are declined, because MathJax, syntax highlighting and other similar features affect performance, but as MathJax is already enabled on your site, I don't expect problems with adding an extension.